# Backslashes being stripped from CSS

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, css, wp-editor

The title explains my problem.  Upon saving CSS stylesheet in the "Appearance > Editor", single backslashes are being stripped out of the stylesheet.

For example:

`content="\foo"`

becomes:

`content="foo"`

I cannot find any solution to this on the web. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Strange, doesn't happen for me in WP 4.2.2. Plugin perhaps??

Comment: This very well could be.....I've started testing that this could be a plugin issue, but haven't gotten too much into it yet.  Thanks for the feedback....

Answer (score 1):

Add a second backslash e.g.

```
content="\\foo"
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you think this could solve the problem?

Comment: @s_ha_dum Makes sense to me. `\ ` is an escape character, so to actually print out a single escape character, you need to escape it. Confusing, huh? So `\\ ` will come out as `\ ` after WP parses it.

Comment: Many people who come here know next to nothing about the software or about programming in general. Answers should therefore include a reasonable explanation.

Comment: This fixed my problem. The WP Theme was developed by some random folks who did strip the CSS content within their Custom CSS editor. Adding two backslashes did fix it. Thanks.